# Discrete Mathematics Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $7$ balls be distributed in four boxes?

Identical balls , several boxes may be empty.
Different boxes!

My solution is 
 $${{n+r-1}\choose{r}}  = {{7+4-1}\choose{4}} = {{10}\choose{4}}.$$ 
But is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to split $n$ equal balls in $k $ different boxes, try proceeding as follows:

Number each box from $1$ to $k $.

Notice that what you are really interested in is the number of balls each box has. Say $x_i$ is the number of balls in box $i $.

Note that you must have $x_1 + \cdots + x_k = n $ and that therefore your problem reduces to finding the number of distinct solutions to this equation where each $x_i $ must be between 0 and $n $.
The number of solutions $S(k, n)$ can be determined with a neat recursion that you should be able to derive if you consider two different cases: all $x_i \not= 0$ or for some $i $, $x_i = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

In how many ways can we write $7$ as a sum of $4$ non-negative integers?

---

Alternatively, you can add up the following:

- Number of permutations of $[0,0,0,7]$, which is $\frac{4!}{3!1!}=4$
- Number of permutations of $[0,0,1,6]$, which is $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}=6$
- Number of permutations of $[0,0,2,5]$, which is $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}=6$
- Number of permutations of $[0,0,3,4]$, which is $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}=6$
- Number of permutations of $[0,1,1,5]$, which is $\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}=6$
- Number of permutations of $[0,1,2,4]$, which is $\frac{4!}{1!1!1!1!}=24$
- Number of permutations of $[0,1,3,3]$, which is $\frac{4!}{1!1!2!}=6$
- Number of permutations of $[0,2,2,3]$, which is $\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}=6$
- Number of permutations of $[1,1,1,4]$, which is $\frac{4!}{3!1!}=4$
- Number of permutations of $[1,1,2,3]$, which is $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}=6$
- Number of permutations of $[1,2,2,2]$, which is $\frac{4!}{1!3!}=4$